# Suppress Load of media resource failed

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have in my html an audio tag, in which I have src="". 
When I play music, I change the src value from javascript. 
However, when loading a page, I get an error

Invalid URI. Load of media resource  failed. game.php
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.

I know why, the source logically does not exist. Is there any way to tell the audio element not to try to load the src from the beginning?

```
<div style="display: none;" >
<audio tabindex="0" id="audio" controls preload="auto" loop="true">
    <source src="">
</audio>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply create your `<audio>` element **without** any `<source>`s, like

```
<audio tabindex="0" id="audio" controls preload="auto" loop="true">
</audio>
```

Then add a `<source>` during runtime, whenever needed/checked/validated, with something like e.g.:

```
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
  
var source = document.createElement('source');console.log(source);
source.setAttribute('src','http://somewhere');
  
audio.appendChild(source);
```

Comment: **pay attention**, must be creating of 'source' element not 'src'. i.e. `var source = document.createElement('source')`. For readers searching console warning in Mozilla "Invalid URI. Load of media resource failed" this answer helped me. also you can set 'type' attribute here, i.e. `source.setAttribute('type', 'audio/ogg')` if you need of course :) _My edits for this answer is not saved for some reason, I placed them in comment_

Answer (score 4):

Remove `<source>` from initial html and then...

```
var a = new Audio('someaudio.mp3');

// File does not exist
a.onerror = function() {
    //nothing
};
//File exists
a.onloadeddata = function() {
    //add source from javascript
};
```